# graphic tools for mean curvature flow

Tags: differential-geometry, math-software, mean-curvature-flows

Does anyone have any suggestions for software that could graphically represent evolution of curves/surfaces under mean curvature flow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried Kenneth Brakke's [Surface evolver](http://www.susqu.edu/brakke/evolver/evolver.html)?

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer some more appealing user interface. Are there any known implementations for Matlab, Mathematica or Maple?

Comment: Speaking of which, @timur, where is a good place to ask questions about Surface Evolver?